# Prove that there is a strict extremum in $x_0$.

Tags: derivatives

Let $f: (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ differentiable in $x_0 \in (a, b)$ and  $f'(x_0) \ \neq 0$

I want to prove that $g(x) = (f(x) - f(x_0))(x - x_0)$ has in $x_0$ severe extremum.

Looks like $f$ is monotonous and we can prove in this case. But what can we say about $g(x)$ to prove this fact?

Comment: $g$ is not defined at $x_0$.

Comment: The one thing you know about $f$ is that for $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that in $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$, $$f'(x_0) -\epsilon < \dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} < f'(x_0) +\epsilon$$.